# Find the number of characters that are present in every line into a List<string>

Tags: c#

I need to find the number of characters that are present in every line, within a List:

So, if for example, the string is

```
Ajdahnfj
Jnbafdbn
Jadnjadg
```

a,j,d,n are common for each line. Therefore the answer is 4.

No case sensitive is required

Regards

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  For example, you could get the set of distinct characters in all lists and then select from that set only characters present in every list.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a high level description of what I would do:

- Make a collection of characters
- initialize it to represent all of the characters in the first line
- for each other line,

  - for each character in the collection, check if it's in that line.  if it isn't then remove it from the list
- return the resulting collection of characters

Comment: +1 for not giving the answer directly

Comment: Thanks, more or less is what I tried, but I would need a hand with the code if someone could help. Cheers

Comment: @marcos82 is there any specific piece that you don't know how to code up?

Comment: The point is that I am beginner with C#, that's why I asked for help..

Comment: @marcos82 is there anything about my answer that you're not understanding?